# Universal Image Loader: how to catch id of browsed image?

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I'am adding a button into ImagePagerActivity to set image as background of the phone.
Function itself works well (I can set app's icon as bg if I set `R.drawable.icon`).

Problem is I strictly don't know how to catch the image id so that people can set as bg the image they are currently browsing. I tried many stuff, but nothing work.

For example, `R.id.image` sends "false", `R.layout.item_pager_image` sends an XML path (ok this is normal, it was just for testing), etc... I really don't know what value I could use to say "hey, put this picture I'm looking at, as my new phone background".

Here is the code I use just before the last `}` in `ImagePagerActivity.java`.
(yes wallpaper code is commented, I print values for debugging)

Thanks for your help !

```
    public void onWallpaperClick(View view) {
        openMyDialog(null);
    }   

    public void openMyDialog(View view) {
        showDialog(10);
    }

    //@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case 10:
            // Create our AlertDialog
            Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Définir cette photo comme fond d'écran de votre appareil ?")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Oui",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // Ends the activity
                                    //HomeActivity.this.finish();
                                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                                    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                                   //try {
                                   //myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.id.image);
                                   //} catch (IOException e) {
                                   // e.printStackTrace();
                                  // }
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            R.drawable.icon,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Non",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Ok !",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

            return builder.create();
        }
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this if theses methods are into the same activity of the displayer :

On ImageLoadingListener::OnLoadingComplete(Bitmap bitmap) methods, you can get the bitmap loaded, so handle the bitmap with an attribute.

```
public class myActivity {
    Bitmap current_bitmap;
{...}
    imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options,
        new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                current_bitmap = loadedImage;
            }
            {...}
        }
}
```

And you can get it to use with WallpaperManager

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
try {
  myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(current_bitmap);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works!... Sometimes. I explain: sometimes the correct image is set as wallpaper, sometimes the image before from the list, sometimes the following image from the list... I don't see logical.

Comment: If it can help, here is the full original Activity file: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/UniversalImageLoaderExample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/ImagePagerActivity.java

Comment: Taklo I am having the same problem as you. did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the image drawable id as its tag, in the xml with android:tag or programatically with ImageView.setTag(), and later get it with the  ImageView.getTag() method.

Comment: Thx I'll try this asap. I'll comment the result.

Comment: I didn't manage to make it. Not sure but I think that with UAL it's not possible, witht he way it loads images.